# Filter logging warnings in JBoss7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

When deploying a Spring project I always get the following warning:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
```

I read here on SO that this is a common warning and the way to deal with it is to filter it (it will still be there, but it will not show). I tried for some time but I can't seem to be able to run in correctly. Here what I do in **standalone-full.xml**:

```
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <filter>
                <not>
                    <match pattern="JBAS011006" />
                </not>
            </filter>
```

I think I tried every possible combination of filter with allow, deny, any an etc. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the problem has been solved anywhere else on SO, but just to document it here:

After having the same problems I resorted to the schema file [jboss-as-logging_1_1.xsd](http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-as-logging_1_1.xsd). (All the XSDs can be found at http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/). It defines the exact places you are allowed to put those filters. The only one place that worked for me was directly in the logger that throws the warning, namely `org.jboss.as.ee`.

So I ended up doing this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    ...
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.ee">
        <filter>
            <not>
                <match pattern="JBAS011006"/>
            </not>
        </filter>
    </logger>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

If this still doesn't work it might be a good idea to check if any logging config files in your project cause interference.

Comment: It looks like the [Logging XSD](https://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-as-logging_1_2.xsd) has changed since JBoss AS 7, but this works in JBoss EAP 6.4.6: 
`<logger category="org.jboss.as.server.deployment">
        <filter-spec value="not(any( match(&quot;JBAS015960&quot;), match(&quot;JBAS015893&quot;) ))"/>
</logger>`

Comment: EAP 6's filtering is documented [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-The_Logging_Subsystem.html#Filter_Expressions_for_Logging). "A `filter-spec` specified for the root logger is _not_ inherited by other loggers. Instead a `filter-spec` must be specified per handler."